# Javascript change text color

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using CkEditor.

**Html:**

```
<script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea name="Editor" class="ckeditor" id="aboutme"></textarea>
```

If textarea value starts with [## and finishes ##] like below

```
"Textxx [##YellowText##] Textxxxx"
```

I want to **set background color yellow and bold all of "[##YellowText##]"**

I can get values of editor by below code however could not go on 
**Javascript:**

```
var x = CKEDITOR.instances["aboutme"].getSelection().getStartElement().getOuterHtml(); // Gets Value of Ckeditor
        alert(x);
```

How can i do this onload page ?

Any help will be appreicated.

Thanks.

Comment: may anybody please help about this onload thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before create an instance of CKEditor run the following code:

```
var ta = document.getElementById('aboutme');
ta.value = ta.value.replace(/(\[##.+?##\])/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow"><strong>$1</strong></span>');
```